# How to optimize for filtering Objects containing a List?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a large list of objects (e.g. cars) that contains a list with subobjects (e.g. parts). Now I want to search on all parts if a property equals something. For example, to get all cars that have a part which has a title containing "seat".

I use `filter` with `NSPredicate(format: "ANY part.title CONTAINS[c] '\(searchTerm)")` on `Results<Car>`

How would I choose the index to optimize queries for that? I can end up having some 100,000 `Car`s with each some 10-20 parts on an iPhone. Does the `Car` need an index on "parts.title"? Or the part on "title"? Or something else?

Comment: Keep in mind that using Swift string interpolation (`"'\(variable)'"`) with `NSPredicate` will often not do what you want (you'll run into escaping issues if your string contains a single quote, for instance). You need to use `NSPredicate`'s object placeholder syntax (`%@`) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, indexes must be declared on the type to which the property belongs. In your example, this would mean the `Part` class should declare that `title` should be indexed. Note however that Realm does not currently use indexes for "contains" searches. They *will* be used for simple equality comparisons (`==`) though.